# Creating new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to create a new view controller programmatically rather than use the storyboard on Xcode. I am quite new to coding and don't understand what value I have to put on in the brackets where frame is. The Code is all on the app delegate, could you please help.

```
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: Homecontroller(frame: -, collectionViewLayout: layout))
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
     window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: HomeController(collectionViewLayout: layout))
```

And your HomeController should be like this

```
class HomeController: UICollectionViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   }
}
```